# how to proceed after registering google are a service provider for allauth

Tags: django, oauth, google-oauth, django-allauth

I want to use the allauth django app.

I did everything described in this allauth tutorial: http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/. I continues until "Now we can login using Django or Facebook" subpart.

After that I can't go to the address that is indicated in the tutorial: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/`

I want you to see the database that I have. its exatly like the tutorial indicates:

[image: allauth socialaccount, socialapp and django_site database view]

This is my setting.py file:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "/srv/http/proj04/proj/templates",

)


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # Required by allauth template tags
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    # allauth specific context processors
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
        'METHOD': 'oauth2'  # instead of 'oauth2'
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'captcha',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    # ... include the providers you want to enable:
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.amazon',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.dropbox',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.flickr',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.instagram',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.openid',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.tumblr',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.vimeo',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk',
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

This is my url.py file:

```
....
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)


urlpatterns += [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I don;t know what to do next.

I tried

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
```

Only to get this exception:

```
DoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
Site matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Site matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /srv/http/proj04/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 310
Python Executable:  /srv/http/proj04/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.1
...
```

or sometimes i get this exception ( i dont know why but these exception alternate):

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/login/

No Facebook app configured: please add a SocialApp using the Django admin

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    

No Facebook app configured: please add a SocialApp using the Django admin

Exception Location:     /srv/http/proj04/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/provider.py in media_js, line 106
Python Executable:  /srv/http/proj04/bin/python
Python Version:     3.4.1
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow this tutorial but substitute FB with google... http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/

Comment: thanks james. but it doesnt work for some reason. I left my steps and the results of them above.

Comment: Your google settings are wrong. Check the settings here http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#google

Comment: You should also only have google listed in your installed apps. So only 'allauth', 'allauth.account', 'allauth.socialaccount', 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google' should be listed from allauth. What happens if you go to http://127.0.0.1:8000?

Comment: Thanks james, I did what you said and it worked. I can't give you credit could you please leave some token answer and i will vote it up.
Say that your answer is in the comments above or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your allauth google settings in your app settings. Take a look at the docs to see what settings are avaliable.

http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#google

You'll also need to change your installed apps to only include these allauth apps

```
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "SITE_ID" in settings.py

django_site table must contain a row with the same value of id (by default equals to 1), as SITE_ID.

And in your SocialApplication table 'localhost:8000/admin/socialaccount/socialapp/' for different providers give this site ID and try to run again, it will work.